# Redirect not working asp.net mvc error 404 despite having the correct location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect to a new page after login. However it does not work.

here is my code for the login check.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind] EmployeModel employe)
    {
        bool employeExiste = employe.LoginCheck(employe);

        if (employeExiste)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("../InventoryLocation/Index");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["msg"] = "Your password is wrong!";
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Here is my file structure.
[image: File structure]

Here is my 404 error.

[image: error 404]

I am new to mvc what am I missing? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change return value to:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","InventoryLocation");
```

and check InventoryLocation to ininheritance Controller

Comment: I still get a 404 error and it open the following link https://localhost:44342/InventoryLocation and not https://localhost:44342/InventoryLocation/index

Comment: both link ,same link. if not include ActionResult set it index

Comment: can see InventoryLocation  Controller?

Comment: ininheritance/Index post method or get method?

Comment: Thank you Mahdi Anjam I did not have a constructeur that returned the view in my inventoryLocation